# Создание BigInteger из String

Tags: java, biginteger

Как избавиться от `Integer.parseInt` в строке:

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(factorial(n - 1)) * n);
```

Метод имеет вид `String factorial(int n)`.

Comment: Вообще говоря, вычислять факториал рекурсивно хоть и привычно для многих, но неверно - т.к это самый очевидный пример рекурсии, его часто дают в разных учебниках(но только как пример!). Так что если вы выполняете не учебное-задание-на-рекурсию, используйте обычный цикл.

Comment: @0xFFh учитывая что метод `factorial` у автора возвращает `String`, то, видимо, вообще невесть что творится в этом методе, абсолютно не связанное с оптимальным способом нахождением факториала числа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(factorial(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

исправить `String factorial(int n)` на  `BigInteger factorial(int n)`

Comment: так не интересно

Comment: об интересах ничего в вопросе не сказано